# kinect v2 joint orientation to unity3d quaternion

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation, kinect

i'm trying to move an avatar using Unity3D according to the data coming from Kinect V2, 
the problem is when i apply multi joint orientations to the unity Slerp transform,

**how can i calculate the new quaternion which allows me to Simulate the realtime human movements correctly?**

```
            float ox, oy, oz, ow;

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.W;
            //SpineMid.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            SpineMid.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(SpineMid.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow), Time.time * 0.1f);
```

[image: here i'm only moving the SpineMid and it seems to be relatively good]

```
            float ox, oy, oz, ow;

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.W;
            //SpineMid.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            SpineMid.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(SpineMid.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow), Time.time * 0.1f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.W;
            //SpineBase.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            SpineBase.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(SpineBase.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow), Time.time * 0.1f);
```

[image: here i'm applying the same Slerp Transform to SpineMid and SpainBase]

the funniest part is when i tried to apply the previous Slerp transformation to every joint in in the avatar

float ox, oy, oz, ow;

```
            ox = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_SpineMid].Orientation.W;
            //SpineMid.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            SpineMid.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(SpineMid.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow), Time.time * 0.1f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_SpineBase].Orientation.W;
            //SpineBase.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            SpineBase.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(SpineBase.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow), Time.time * 0.1f);


            ox = body.JointOrientations[_Neck].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_Neck].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_Neck].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_Neck].Orientation.W;
            //Neck.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            Neck.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Neck.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_Head].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_Head].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_Head].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_Head].Orientation.W;
            //Head.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            Head.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Head.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderRight].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderRight].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderRight].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderRight].Orientation.W;
            //ShoulderRight.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            ShoulderRight.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(ShoulderRight.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowRight].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowRight].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowRight].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowRight].Orientation.W;
            //ElbowRight.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            ElbowRight.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(ElbowRight.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_HandRight].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_HandRight].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_HandRight].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_HandRight].Orientation.W;
            //HandRight.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            HandRight.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(HandRight.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderLeft].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderLeft].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderLeft].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_ShoulderLeft].Orientation.W;
            //ShoulderLeft.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            ShoulderLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(ShoulderLeft.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowLeft].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowLeft].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowLeft].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_ElbowLeft].Orientation.W;
            //ElbowLeft.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            ElbowLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(ElbowLeft.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_HandLeft].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_HandLeft].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_HandLeft].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_HandLeft].Orientation.W;
            //HandLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox*360, oz*360, oy*360, ow*360), 0.03f);
            HandLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(HandLeft.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_HipsLeft].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_HipsLeft].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_HipsLeft].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_HipsLeft].Orientation.W;
            //HipsLeft.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            HipsLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(HipsLeft.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_KneeRight].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_KneeRight].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_KneeRight].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_KneeRight].Orientation.W;
            //KneeRight.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            KneeRight.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(KneeRight.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleRight].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleRight].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleRight].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleRight].Orientation.W;
            //AnkleRight.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            AnkleRight.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(AnkleRight.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_FootRight].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_FootRight].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_FootRight].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_FootRight].Orientation.W;
            //FootRight.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            FootRight.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(FootRight.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_HipsRight].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_HipsRight].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_HipsRight].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_HipsRight].Orientation.W;
            //HipsRight.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            HipsRight.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(HipsRight.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_KneeLeft].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_KneeLeft].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_KneeLeft].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_KneeLeft].Orientation.W;
            //KneeLeft.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            KneeLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(KneeLeft.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleLeft].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleLeft].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleLeft].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_AnkleLeft].Orientation.W;
            //AnkleLeft.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            AnkleLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(AnkleLeft.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);

            ox = body.JointOrientations[_FootLeft].Orientation.X;
            oy = body.JointOrientations[_FootLeft].Orientation.Y;
            oz = body.JointOrientations[_FootLeft].Orientation.Z;
            ow = body.JointOrientations[_FootLeft].Orientation.W;
            //FootLeft.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(ox, oy, oz, ow);
            FootLeft.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(FootLeft.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(ox * 360, oy * 360, oz * 360, ow * 360), 0.03f);
```

[image: applying Slerp Transformation to every joint in the avatar]

Note: all those print screens was taken with T-Pose facing the KinectV2 Sensor.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I believe I may have a similar issue.

Comment: @dudledok not yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, the orientations are not local and you need to orient each joint to the sky, before applying the respective orientation.